# Identify loop or recursion in the list

Tags: java, list, loops, recursion

I want to identify the loop or recursion in the list for the below structure of the node. How can I identify the same?

```
public class EntityNode {
    private EntityNode nextNode; // Points to the next node
}
```

Example,

```
Node1 -> Node2 -> Node3 -> Node4 -> Node5 -> Node6 -> Node4
```

Here, you can see that `Node6` is pointing to `Node4`, and here there comes the looping or recursion and my code will go into infinite. So what if I want to find out this type of scenario with the optimum performance level?

Comment: So you want to detect a cycle in a graph?

Comment: @C.B. Yes you can say that

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: @PM77-1 As I just came into thsese scenario logically, I have not tried anything technically, just logically I have faced this situation.

Comment: @C.B., thanks for the quick response, but I am looking for the Java code for the same with performence optimized way

Comment: OK. It means that's it the time to try to code some solution.

Comment: @PM77-1 Yes, but it should have performence optimized way

Comment: No, first you need to have **a** solution, then you can start thinking of a better one.

Comment: @PM77-1 yes you are right, but as I said I have faced this situation just logically and not technically as I am not able to code the same

Comment: As you should already know, SO is **not** "*write a code for me*" site. We are here to give you pointers - not to do your job.

Comment: @PM77-1 Yes I totally agree with you, but I was just asking if anybody can help

Comment: And you got good pointers, but you keep asking for the exact implementation, don't you?  Here's a direct quote: "Please write code as and when you get time, as it is very urgent for me".

Comment: @PM77-1 Yes I am, but please help me out if you can as quick as possible as I am not able to even start my work now

Comment: @BhavikAmbani do you just want to see if your list has a cycle or do you need the identify the cycle as well? If it is the former then I would look into a [Bloomfilter](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/HashingExplained#BloomFilter).

Comment: @BhavikAmbani : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663115/how-to-detect-a-loop-in-a-linked-list

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494830/how-to-determine-if-a-linked-list-has-a-cycle-using-only-two-memory-locations

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is actually an interview question I have heard a few times. While I have never tried to implement any sort of loop detection, the answer that most of the interviewers seemed to like is iterating through the list and storing the visited nodes in a hashtable. If you get a collision while storing into the table, then you have a loop in your list.

Edit: In an attempt to offer some code for the example, here is what I would probably try to do (assuming you have some sort of `LinkedList<EntityNode>` object). I updated this to use a HashSet instead of a HashMap so it was more straightforward (as pointed out by PM 77-1).

```
public bool detectLoop(LinkedList<EntityNode> list)
{
    Set<EntityNode> nodeSet = new HashSet<EntityNode>();
    EntityNode curNode = list.getHead();
    boolean loopDetected = false;

    if(curNode != null)
    {
        while(curNode.getNextNode() != null && !loopDetected)
        {
            cureNode = curNode.getNextNode();
            loopDetected = !nodeSet.add(curNode);
        }
    }

    return loopDetected;
}
```

I haven't had the opportunity to test this, but this should work. The reason being that the `add()` method for a HashSet returns `true if this set did not already contain the specified element`. So if there is a EntityNode already exists in the set, it will return false, meaning that there was a loop detected.

Since my answer has sort of taken off, I want to say that there are other solutions to this as well. The other one that has been pointed out in this thread is the tortoise and the hare algorithm. You can find more information on that in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663115/how-to-detect-a-loop-in-a-linked-list) or at [this wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Tortoise_and_hare).

Comment: I've added a code example that should work, or at least show the logic behind my answer. Note that I didn't test the code though, so be careful not to blindly adhere to it.

Comment: I think an implementation via `HashSet` would be more straightforward, since its `add()` method returns `boolean`.

Comment: You are correct, a HashSet would make much more sense here. I've updated the example to use a HashSet instead.

Comment: @endorphins Please find my answer

Comment: This solution is fine but you have to keep in mind that in the worst case scenario your hashset will grow as n-1 elements. Also you have to search throught all your hashmap for every new node. So if you are planing to have a big graph list you should think of a better algorithm.

Comment: For this to work correctly all the time you need to implement hashCode().  You're relying on !nodeSet.add(curNode) which I suspect might not work correctly if you had a hash code collision [because you relied on the default implementation](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6321873).

Comment: @molokoV Yes this is true. If you are worried about the size of the hashset then it would probably be better to use the other algorithm pointed out in this thread (I also included mention of it in my answer in case people don't read other answers)

Comment: @JohnR Do you have another link for that bug? The one you provided doesn't point me to an available bug.

Comment: @endorphins, unfortunately I don't have a working link.  The link worked when I posted it last week.  Basically it was a "closed/won't fix" that proposed changing the Javadocs to show that hashCode wasn't unique.

Answer (score 8):

You should have two EntityNode objects. Both start at Node1. Have the first object move two nodes down, and the second only move one node down. Repeat this until you either reach the end (there was no cycle) or the two objects meet at the same node (there is a cycle).

For your example:

n1: Node1, n2: Node1

n1: Node3, n2: Node2

n1: Node5, n2: Node3

n1: Node4, n2: Node4 -> cycle!!

---

For pseudocode:

```
while (n1.nextNode isn't null):
    n1 = n1.nextNode.nextNode
    n2 = n2.nextnode
    if (n1 equals n2): return 'there is a loop!'
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, But can you represent this thing technically with code in Java ?

Comment: For Java, you can make the pointers two EntityNode objects, and to move them, replace them once/twice with their nextNode.

Comment: But by this was I can not waste memory

Comment: You can have:  while node1 doesnt equal node2 and node1 hasn't reached the end, node1 = node1.nextNode.nextNode, node2 = nextNode.

Comment: you only ever have two objects in memory

Comment: @ashokramcse - C'mon. He meant references.

Comment: @olgash please find my answer

Comment: @PM77-1 Please find my answer

Answer (score 3):

I searched on the net and found that this type of problem is called  the *tortoise and hare algorithm*. The Wikipedia page is also [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Tortoise_and_hare) for the same.

As codaddict states in [their answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2663147/19679):

> The idea is to have two references to the list and move them at
>   **different speeds**. Move one forward by `1` node and the other by `2` nodes.
>
> - If the linked list has a loop they will *definitely* meet.
> - Else either of the two references(or their `next`) will become `null`.
>
> **Java code implementing the algorithm:**
>
> ```
> boolean hasLoop(EntityNode first) {
>   if (first == null) // list does not exist..so no loop either.
>       return false;
>   EntityNode slow, fast; // create two references.
>   slow = fast = first; // make both refer to the start of the list.
>   while (true) {
>       slow = slow.nextNode; // 1 hop.
>       if (fast.nextNode != null)
>           fast = fast.nextNode; // 2 hops.
>       else
>           return false; // next node null => no loop.
>       if (slow == null || fast == null) // if either hits null..no loop.
>           return false;
>       if (slow == fast) // if the two ever meet...we must have a loop.
>           return true;
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: isn't this exactly what olgash said?

Comment: Get's a +1 from me. Naming the algorithm so that it can be looked up elsewhere is the most important thing from an answer.

Comment: You actually only did one hop and not 2. You forgot one `fast = fast.nextNode`.

Comment: @ThomasMueller Thanks for the suggestion, appriciated .

Comment: @BhavikAmbani it was not a suggestion, it was a bug report :-)

Comment: @ThomasMueller So thanks for the bug report :) :) :) :)

Comment: If the list is [1,2,3,4,1,6]: Step 0(slow=1,fast=1)  Step 1(slow=2 fast=3) Step 3(slow=3 fast=6) Step 4(slow=4 fast=null) End.
Thus, loop is not detected, though there is.
Am i missing something or misinterpreting something?

Comment: When you copy the words of others, you must both quote the copied text and link to the original. I have done this in the above, but you must be sure to do this yourself in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can make a "visited" flag. Or you can use unintersecting sets, which helps to identify loops in O(N *log N).
P.S. I must admit that this method is more appropriate if you need to build a graph without cycles.

Comment: I think it is not advisable to put such flags in the class, lets say if I have any other requirement then should I place another flag in the class ?

Comment: What about the second way?

Comment: @BhavikAmbani It may or may not be appropriate.  You have to remember to clear all the flags after you're done checking for the cycle.  It also is not thread-safe.  But if you're careful, a "visited" flag can work and may be more efficient than using a map, but probably not much more.

Comment: @ajb I personally was exposed to such task and used the second way. But as this version of task seemed pretty easy, I also proposed flags

Comment: @BhavikAmbani Unfortunately, not now. But all you have to do is actually implement a tree, where each node knows the father. So that when you come to the new node, you check whether it's already in the set, if not just add to the current, if yes ( I am not sure about whether graphs can have several components in your case ) then you check if this is the same set. If so - there is cycle. If not - connect two sets.
That is the algorithm, although I haven't mentioned euristics

Comment: @BhavikAmbani Here http://e-maxx.ru/algo/dsu you can find some C++ code examples. Sorry for non-English)

Comment: @Anjenson Please find my answer

Answer (score 0):

I like Bhavik's answer if you are constrained by memory limits.  It doesn't create any possibly large objects to determine the answer.

If there is a loop then the single step and double step methods of walking through the EntityNodes will have to intersect.

Here is sample code to test with -

```
public class EntityNode {
    private EntityNode nextNode = null; // Points to the next node

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final EntityNode head = new EntityNode();

        // Create small sample (test with even and odd number)
        EntityNode tail = head;
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            EntityNode newNode = new EntityNode();
            tail.nextNode = newNode;
            tail = newNode;
        }

        // Add "loop" node
        tail.nextNode = head;

        System.out.println(detectLoop(head));
    }

    // Return true if a loop is found
    private static boolean detectLoop(EntityNode head) {
        boolean loopDetected = false;

        if (head != null) {
            EntityNode singleStep = head;
            EntityNode doubleStep = head;

            // If either EntityNode is null and end has been found
            while ((singleStep.nextNode != null)
                    && (doubleStep.nextNode != null)) {
                singleStep = singleStep.nextNode;

                // Assert doubleStepper.nextNode != null
                doubleStep = doubleStep.nextNode.nextNode;

                // If there is a "Collision" then there is a loop
                loopDetected = (doubleStep == singleStep);
                if (loopDetected) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return loopDetected;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just traverse the list while keeping every visited node in a hash set. If the node you are adding is ever already present in the set, you have a cycle.

Answer (score 0):

A.-Keep count of the amount of added nodes. Then start a loop through them, while counting the loops. If loopsAmount>nodesAmount, you have recursion.

B.-Keep track of the visited nodes. If a node is visited twice, you have recursion.

C.-Index the nodes while creating them. If node.nextNode.Index-1 != node.Index, you have recursion.